# How do I use Spring Boot when Jetty 9.3 is on the classpath?

Tags: spring, solr, spring-boot, jetty, jetty-9

I have a Spring Boot project, and I am trying to upgrade from Solr 5.4 to Solr 6.1.  Solr 6.1 has a dependency to Jetty 9.3.  Now Spring Boot complains:  it gives a `NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler$NoContext`.  ContextHandler exists in Jetty 9.3, but not the inner class NoContext.

Is there a way of solving this?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:49)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptSetupMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:88)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.TestRuleInterceptor.intercept(TestRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:364)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler$NoContext
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler$NoContext
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.newServletHandler(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.getServletHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.relinkHandlers(ServletContextHandler.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:201)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.<init>(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:28)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$NoContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: Spring Boot latest versions use Jetty 9. Which Spring Boot version do you have? Spring Boot 1.3.5 uses Jetty 9.2.16.v20160414, but maybe you can face some problems when trying to configure 9.3 if it's not fully backwards compatible.

Comment: What version of Boot are you using? Jetty 9.3 should work with Boot 1.3.x. While it's not the default, we have a [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/1.3.x/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty93) that checks it works. Spring Boot 1.4 will use Jetty 9.3 by default.

Comment: @XtremeBiker: `ContextHandler$NoContext` disappeared in Jetty 9.3 (it was there in 9.2)

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: I use Spring Boot 1.3.5.  I'll check the sample, thanks.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: Any idea how I can set `jetty.version` in Gradle?

Comment: @neu242 It's described in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-dependency-versions

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot 1.3.6, following jetty gradle config worked fine:

```
dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
compile("org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.3.10.v20160621")
compile("org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:9.2.17.v20160517")
```